# Java Comparator comparing two different fields against one another

Tags: java, sorting

I'm wondering if I can use a Comparator to compare two different fields with one another. A simple example would be making a linear chain where each Object has a head and a tail and the head and tail of each Object will respectively be a tail or head of another Object. For this simple example I'm assuming all Objects have a head and a tail and the chain is always linear without gaps.

```
public class Link {
    private Object head;
    private Object tail;
...
}
```

And to build the chain. I really don't care whether it's ascending or descending.

```
LinkedList<Link> chain ...
chain.sort((o1, o2) -> {

        if (o1 != null && o2 != null) {
            if (Objects.equals(o1.getHead(), o2.getTail())) {
                return -1;
            }

            if (Objects.equals(o1.getTail(), o2.getHead())) {
                return 1;
            }
        }

        return 0;
    });
```

The problem here is that returning zero when there is no relationship between adjacent links in the original list order will mean that the items just stay in that current order. I know I can accomplish this through a more manual iteration of the original list and the list I'm building but I'm curious if there's a way to accomplish this via a Comparator.

Comment: Probably not.  This really isn't a valid use case for `Comparator`.

Comment: Whatever you are doing there it has nothing to do with sorting. To sort you need a commutative relation. In other words the two statements `Y < X` and `X > Y` must be equivalent.

Comment: I'm tending to agree with @LouisWasserman that perhaps the answer to my brain exercise here is that a Comparator just doesn't work. Whether you call it sorting or ordering the commutative relationship exists when looking at the entire chain as a whole, but not when comparing just X and Y, which is exactly what the Comparator does. Thanks for the thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

In order to sort the objects, we need to have heads and tails be comparable. For instance, calling o1.getHead().compare(o2.getTail()) should yield a number indicating whether the head comes before the tail or vice versa.

Assuming the head and tail objects have comparators, we can then do something like this:

```
chain.sort((o1, o2) -> {
    if (o1 != null && o2 != null) {
        return o1.getHead().compare(o2.getTail())
    }
    return 0;
});
```

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but for what I'm currently working on I can't do this and I think that's why it's difficult or impossible to do via a Comparator. I have it done via a manual looping but at this point it was more of a brain exercise. Thanks for the answer.